# Regular Expression for String without a "?" character to redirect to string with "?" character

Tags: regex, redirect

On our website we occasionally experience an error where dynamic links aren't building correctly.

**URLs like this**
https://www.test.url.edu/collections/&edan_fq[]=p.edanmdm.indexedstructured.object_type:%22Financial+records%22&edan_fq[]=p.edanmdm.descriptivenonrepeating.record_id:item_*

**Should actually be this:**

https://www.test.url.edu/collections/search?edan_fq[]=p.edanmdm.indexedstructured.object_type:%22Financial+records%22&edan_fq[]=p.edanmdm.descriptivenonrepeating.record_id:item_*

We want to create a regular expression to redirect

/collections/&edan_fq[]=

to

/collections/search?edan_fq[]=

But everything after "edan_fq[]=" can change dynamically--there are thousands of permutations of the string after that point.

Does anyone know how this would be done?

Comment: So you just need to swap the first `&` to a `?` right?

Comment: What is regex flavor or tool?

Comment: [*Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use regular expressions.”  Now they have two problems.* - Jamie Zawinski](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247)

Comment: Just do a string replace of `/collections/&edan_fq[]=` to `/collections/search?edan_fq[]=`

Answer (score 0):

If you use `\&` without `Global Flag` in Regex it will give first match. I've used `JavaScript`, please check this.

```js
var data = "https://www.test.url.edu/collections/&edan_fq[]=p.edanmdm.indexedstructured.object_type:%22Financial+records%22&edan_fq[]=p.edanmdm.descriptivenonrepeating.record_id:item_*";

var regex = /\&/
data = data.replace(regex,"search?");
console.log(data);
```

Please check Substitution example in [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/H0B0Aa/1).